# Return statement inside two loops

Tags: java, netbeans

***When I run this code on Netbeans IDE v11.1***

```
         for(int x = 3; x >0; x--)
             for(int y = 3; y >= x; y--) {
                 System.err.println(x + "  " + y);
                 if(x == 1 && y == 2) { // any if statement
                    System.out.println("KKKK");
                    return;
                 }
             }
```

***The "KKKK" should be at the end of the output so the expected output is*** :

```
    3  3
    2  3
    2  2
    1  3
    1  2
    KKKK
```

***But what i get in netbeans is***

```
    3  3
    KKKK
    2  3
    2  2
    1  3
    1  2
```

***And the position of "KKKK" changes randomly in the output***

***What happens?***

Comment: You're writing to two different streams. Don't.

Comment: also: stop thinking your choice of IDE has an impact on this.

Comment: JB Nizet Yeah that is right... I got it. Thaks